# Elixir: Update list of maps

Tags: elixir

Let's assume that we have the following:

```
list = 
[
  %{"id" => 1, "name" => "Alice"},
  %{"id" => 2, "name" => "Bob"},
  %{"id" => 3, "name" => "Charlie"}
]
```

In order to add key `type` with a value `person` to each element we could do:
`list |> Enum.map(fn x -> Map.put(x, "type", "person") end)` which will result in:

```
[
  %{"id" => 1, "name" => "Alice", "type" => "person"},
  %{"id" => 3, "name" => "Bob", "type" => "person"},
  %{"id" => 3, "name" => "Charlie", "type" => "person"}
]
```

Now, let's say that we have another list:

```
types = ["human", "alien", "unknown"]
```

How to combine `list` and `types` so that the end result will be:

```
[
  %{"id" => 1, "name" => "Alice", "type" => "human"},
  %{"id" => 2, "name" => "Bob", "type" => "alien"},
  %{"id" => 2, "name" => "Charlie", "type" => "unknown"}
]
```

?

Answer (score 2):

Using [`Enum.zip/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#zip/2) and [`Enum.map/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#map/2) should do the trick:

```
list
|> Enum.zip(types)
|> Enum.map(fn {list, type} -> Map.put(list, "type", type) end)

[
  %{"id" => 1, "name" => "Alice", "type" => "human"},
  %{"id" => 2, "name" => "Bob", "type" => "alien"},
  %{"id" => 3, "name" => "Charlie", "type" => "unknown"}
]
```

Answer (score 2):

These are both perfectly good answers, but for the sake of completion I just wanted to include two more options, which can achieve both the "zip" and "map" phases in one single pass:

1. Writing a recursive function

```
  def zip_persons([], []), do: []

  def zip_persons([person | persons], [type | types]) do
    [Map.put(person, "type", type) | zip_persons(persons, types)]
  end
```

2. This is still not released, but from Elixir 1.12 you will be able to use [`Enum.zip_with/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Enum.html#zip_with/3) for this case. I'm mentioning it in case somebody finds this post after it gets released :)

```
Enum.zip_with(list, types, fn person, type -> Map.put(person, "type", type) end)
```

Comment: `Enum.zip_with/3` is released and this should be the accepted answer.

`Enum.zip_with(list, types, &(Map.put(&1, :type, &2)))`

Answer (score 1):

While Daniel’s answer is perfectly correct, one might achieve more fine-grained control over what to do if lists are of different length with [`Enum.reduce/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#reduce/3)

```
list
|> Enum.reduce({types, []}, fn
  e, {[], acc} -> {[], [Map.put(e, "type", "unknown") | acc]}
  e, {[t |ts], acc} -> {ts, [Map.put(e, "type", t) | acc]}
end)
|> elem(1)
```

or with [`Enum.reduce_while/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#reduce_while/3)

```
list
|> Enum.reduce_while({types, []}, fn
  e, {[], acc} -> {:halt, {[], [Map.put(e, "type", "unknown") | acc]}}
  e, {[t |ts], acc} -> {:cont, {ts, [Map.put(e, "type", t) | acc]}}
end)
|> elem(1)
```